# Eclipse: Installing Android SDK...Losing java

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've tried downloading Android SDK for eclipse multiple times, and each time I download, I lose everything in eclipse other than CVS. I have no idea why. I am on a Linux machine

Comment: I'm not sure but try to open  Eclipse as a manager it always helps me in windeows , I do not work on Linux

Answer (score 0):

try to download from here, you download the Eclipse with SDK installed.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

bellow you have other plataforms choose your 32/64, and download ADT is the one full.

Answer (score 0):

Download [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) so you can leave your other Eclipse intact. ADT bundle comes with a preconfigured Eclipse run `<adt-bundle-dir>/eclipse/eclipse`.